# Python: read file - modify line - write output

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of terms in a file that I want to read, modify each term and output the new terms to a new file. The new terms should look like this: take the first two characters of the original term put them in quotes, add a '=>' then the original term in quotes and a comma.

This is the code I'm using:

```
def newFile(newItem):
    original = line
    first = line[0:2]
    newItem = first+'=>'+original+',' 
    return newItem
input = open('/Users/george/Desktop/input.txt', 'r')
output = open('/Users/george/Desktop/output.txt', 'w')
collector = ''
for line in input: 
   if len(line) != 0:
       collector = newFile(input)
       output.write(''.join(collector))
   if len(line) == 0:
       input.close()
output.close()
```

For example: 
If the terms in the input.txt file are these: 
    term 1
    term 2
    term 3
    term 4

The output is this:

```
te=>term 1
,te=>term 2
,te=>term 3
,te=>term 4    
,
```

How can I add `''` to the first two letters and to the term? And why the second, third and forth terms have `,te` not `te` like it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `collector` and `newFile()` you can use new variable:

```
modified_line = "'%s'=>'%s',"  % (line[:2], line.strip())
```

and in your loop try this:

```
...
if len(line) > 2:
    output.write('%s\n' % (modified_line))
```

Also:

- if possible do not hard code file names in your program, use `sys.argv`, standard input/output or config file; of course if you are sure of input/output names then use them
- in `line[0:2]` you can ommit 0 and use line`[:2]`
- you should use `try:` - open file - read file etc. `finally:` close file
- you don't need to check if `len(line) == 0`, `for` loop do it already and you will receive line with CRLF for empty lines, but end of input file is when `for` loop ends